# Unable to set Sharepoint column lookup value using PnP

Tags: powershell

I want to upload a file to Sharepoint and assign a value to one of the columns. Something like `Add-PnPFile -Path "path\test.txt" -Folder "My Folder" -Values @{"Test Column" = "test"}` works fine if the column is of a single line text type.

However, if the column is a lookup column it does not work. My file gets uploaded but the field is not populated. Powershell generates no error.

I used `Get-PnpListItem -List "My List"` to get the ID of the item I want to assign and then `Add-PnPFile -Path "path\test.txt" -Folder "My Folder" -Values @{"Test Column" = 123}` to upload the file.

According to the documentation this should work but alas it doesn't.
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFile.html

How can I assign a value to a lookup column from powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. If you have a space in your column name, "my column" is not sufficient, instead you have to write it out as `-Values @{"my_x0020_column" = 123}`. A space is denied as `_x0020_`.